# How to split Data-Frame into train and validation data set (given below in image) based on the picking random list of 2 from column ['Seen_A']

Tags: python, pandas

How to split Data-Frame into train and validation data set (given below in image) based on the picking random list of 2 from column.
i.e. Split it into two Data-Frame by randomly picking few list in column of dataframe

[image]

Comment: I don't understant on which condition you want to do your split. what do you call by "picking random list of 2 from column" ? if you just want to split your df into two random df, use sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split

Comment: Want to split the data into two (train and validation data set) by on basis of columns by random pick of few list in one train and rest in other Validation

Comment: see the image of data I kept in starting

Answer (score 0):

you could use numpy random choice. Supose you have a dataFrame called df:

```
import numpy as np

nTrain = 2#desired first set length
trainIdx = np.random.choice(len(df), nTrain,replace=False)
trainDF  = df.iloc[trainIdx]
trstDF   = df.drop(trainIdx)
```